# Error installing libpcl-dev ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcl-dev
```

It is giving the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcl-
dev_1.7.2-14build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):

trying to overwrite '/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/for_each_type.h', which is
also in package libpcl-common-1.7-dev 1.7.2-1+trusty6 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpcl-dev_1.7.2-14build1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I do not have any clue how to resolve the issue. Please help.

Comment: Suggest : Remove the old Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) **libpcl*** packages, and then install the Ubuntu 16.04 `libpcl-dev`

Comment: Will it not cause any kind of unmet dependency issues for other packages(such as openCV) which were installed in 14.04? I have upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.

Comment: You can try `$ sudo apt remove libpcl-common-1.7-dev` ... and watch if OK. Usually you will have to confirm ( Yes / no ). ... Why do you want "libpcl-dev"? I.e. same version as the 14.04 package.

Comment: It is giving me several errors like:                                                                                   libpcl-features-1.7-dev : Depends: libpcl-common-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed.  Can you tell me why these two are having conflicts?

Comment: `libpcl-features-1.7-dev` is another old package. Not available any more. Was once available (for a short time)  for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. Suggest : Remove it.

Comment: Solved it via removing all the broken packages from Synaptic Package Manager.